# How to define types for Cypress task return type?

Tags: typescript, cypress

My objective is to define types for my cypress task, written in typescript.

I currently have this when I consume the custom task:

```js
cy.task('customTask').then(v => {
   // v is undefined here - how can I configure types?
});
```

**plugins/index.ts**

```js
module.exports = (on) => {
  on('task', {
    customTask: () => {
      return 23;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't really return types.  Instead, it returns objects with key value pairs.  In Typescript you may cast an object to a type like this example person:Person = personObject.  The success is dependent on the accuracy of the personObject.  Did it have values for all fields? Were they correct?  Etc.

Comment: @Daule I have tried your code in my test and I am getting value 23 in test without any issues. I am using cypress version 5.0.0

Comment: @soccerway can you attach a screenshot of that? Do you have typings for the return type - when you consume the `customTask`?

Comment: How can i attached screenshot in comments ? Is that possible ?

Comment: I don't think you can attach a screenshot in comments, but maybe leave a link to imgur or something?

Answer (score 3):

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            task(event: 'customTask'): Chainable<number>;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add some surrounding information and avoid posting code-only answers.